# Make onKeyDown trigger an HTML button's onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a basic HTML form named Calculator, with a button named "btnOne". What I want is for when the user presses the <kbd>1</kbd> key on the keyboard, the "btnOne" HTML button's onClick event to occur.

To attempt to accomplish this, I placed this function in the Head tag of my document:

```
<head>
     <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
             
         //other functions...

        document.onkeydown = function(e){
            if (!e) e = window.event;
            if(e.keycode == '49') {
                document.Calculator.btnOne.click();
            }
            return false;
        }
      </SCRIPT>
</head>
```

Am I just putting this snippet in the wrong spot? Is there something else I need to do to make the function run? I'm really a beginner with web development and don't know what I'm doing! Of course, once I get figured out how to get this button to work, I will add if statements for all of the other buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check out http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ for a much easier and cleaner way to write this.  What you have is basically right, though you'd do well to wrap this in a document ready event, so that the events bind *after* the dom has loaded.

with jQuery your code would look something like this

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(window).keypress(function(e){
         if (e.which === 49) {
               jQuery("#btnOne").click();
         }
    });
})
```

heres a working JS Fiddle that will demonstrate this

http://jsfiddle.net/HXYAD/

However, its probably a good idea to abstract out the event handler for the click into a parameterized function so that you dont have

```
 jQuery('#btnOne').click(function(){
     //some code
 });

 jQuery('#btnTwo').click(function(){
     //some similar code
 });     
 jQuery('#btnThree').click(function(){
     //some more similar code
 });
```

Comment: This is definitely helping. It's my first try using jQuery, so I think I'm having some trouble with that. I tried putting in this jQuery function, and Firebug is giving me the error message "jQuery is not defined."  I do already have an event handler called handleBtnClick that all of the buttons are using.

Comment: Also, I put the code in a jsfiddle and it works for half a second, and then the whole form disappers and says: {"error": "Please use POST request"}. Any ideas?

Comment: well, if you're getting jQuery is not defined, then you probably havent included a jquery file. http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

could you post the jsFiddle for me to see what you mean?

Comment: Thanks guys, with a little playing around and some googling, I got it all working! Thanks a ton